# Wifi not working on HP 15-AU114NA on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, xubuntu, iwlwifi

I am new to Ask Ubuntu, this is literally my first question :-)

I purchased an HP laptop (15-AU114NA) and installed Ubuntu 16.04LTS (together with Windows 10).

When I use Ubuntu, my laptop Wi-fi does not work. It works on Windows 10.

I ran the following terminal command:

```
lshw -c network
```

The result is the following:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED description: Network controller product: Intel Corporation vendor: Intel Corporation physical id: 0 bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0 version: 10 width: 64 bits clock: 33MHz capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list configuration: latency=0 resources: memory:b1000000-b1001fff
```

When I run this command:

```
lspci -vvnn
```

I get this:

```
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
DeviceName: Intel Dual BandWireless-AC 3168 802.11 ac 1x1 WiFi + BT 4.0 Combo Adapter
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2110]
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 11
Region 0: Memory at b1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
```

NOTE: for other results (example for Ethernet) there is a "Kernel module" reference that I could identify and load, but not for Wifi...

I found the drivers for my Wifi built-in chip (3168) http://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html I downloaded the drivers, then I unzipped and copied (using sudo...) in the following directory:

```
/lib/firmware
```

But still no luck :-( (no Wifi available)

Actually I checked this directory using the following command:

```
ls -l
```

And here is what I got:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root      root      1028032 Mar 28 08:22 iwlwifi-3168-22.ucode
drwxr-xr-x  2 guillaume guillaume    4096 Feb 26 21:33 **iwlwifi-3168-ucode-22.361476.0**
```

So here already I see that my copy does not have the same format that other files (owner is me instead of root, and read/write/executable status is different), I guess I should do a chmod to solve that? Also checking the line above I realise that actually there is already a driver for my wifi as it has the same name structure (3168-22.ucode) so I am even wondering if I needed to copy the firmware in this directory because it seems now (since Mar 28) there is a driver already in this directory...

@all any idea of what to do to solve my Wifi issue?

Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: What is the kernel version?

Comment: Hello Pilot6, you mentioned it is a possible duplicate of ... I followed the link and indeed, this gentleman had the same problem, and someone posted a response that is actually the solution to my problem! I am super grateful, this forum is great, my problem is now sorted and there is no way I could have sorted that by myself. A big thanks to all!